# Como poner privilegios de usuarios en menus de ventana principal en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión el cual si esta funcionando bien, pero le quiero agregar privilegios para cada usuario, en formulario principal tengo tres menús (vehículos,Reportes y Registros) me logeo con el nombre de cargo y contraseña que así lo base de datos, por decir cuando entro con el tipo de cargo Supervisor ahí me muestra toda la ventana ya que es como el administrador y tiene todos los privilegios, pero cuando entro con tipo de cargo Guardia1 ahí quiero que el menú registro sea restringido que no sea visible, ya que lo hice con  un condicional pero no se aplica la restricción para el usuario Guardia1.

Este es mi código:

```
private void ingresarSesion()
    {
        MySqlConnection conexionBD = Conexion.conexion();
        conexionBD.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE cargo = '"+textUsuario.Text+"' AND contraseña= '"+textContraseña.Text+"'",conexionBD);

            MySqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();

            if ( leer.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido: "+textUsuario.Text, "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                
                Principal principal = new Principal();
                if (textUsuario.Text == "Supervisor")
                {
                    principal.ShowDialog();

                }

                else if (textUsuario.Text == "Guardia1")
                {
                    principal.ShowDialog();
                    principal.menuRegistro.Visible = false;
                }

                this.Hide();
             
                Application.Restart();
               
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario o Contraseña son incorrectos, vuelva a intentarlo ", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }  
        }
        catch ( MySqlException ex )
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error al iniciar sesión:  " + ex.Message, "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           

        }
        finally
        {
            conexionBD.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invierte el orden de las sentencias primero pon: principal.menuRegistro.Visible = false; y despues principal.ShowDialog();

Comment: Gracias camarada Japv ya lo había arreglado, era ese pequeño detalle tal como lo mencionas, a veces por las prisas surgen esos detalles.